# BDB JE com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException

Tags: berkeley-db

When I use BDB JE to build a HA application, I meet the exception:

```
com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException: (JE 6.4.9) Group key: $$GROUP_KEY$$ is missing UNEXPECTED_STATE: Unexpected internal state, may have side effects.
at com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException.unexpectedState(EnvironmentFailureException.java:426)
at com.sleepycat.je.rep.impl.RepGroupDB.fetchGroup(RepGroupDB.java:416)
at com.sleepycat.je.rep.impl.RepGroupDB.getGroup(RepGroupDB.java:255)
at com.sleepycat.je.rep.impl.RepGroupDB.getGroup(RepGroupDB.java:288)
at com.sleepycat.je.rep.impl.node.RepNode.refreshCachedGroup(RepNode.java:858)
at com.sleepycat.je.rep.impl.node.RepNode.findMaster(RepNode.java:1201)
at com.sleepycat.je.rep.impl.node.RepNode.startup(RepNode.java:827)
at com.sleepycat.je.rep.impl.node.RepNode.joinGroup(RepNode.java:2031)
at com.sleepycat.je.rep.impl.RepImpl.joinGroup(RepImpl.java:590)
at com.sleepycat.je.rep.ReplicatedEnvironment.joinGroup(ReplicatedEnvironment.java:581)
at com.sleepycat.je.rep.ReplicatedEnvironment.<init>(ReplicatedEnvironment.java:643)
at com.sleepycat.je.rep.ReplicatedEnvironment.<init>(ReplicatedEnvironment.java:489)
at com.tencent.hippo.broker.service.impl.DefStoreManagerService.getEnvironment(DefStoreManagerService.java:574)
at com.tencent.hippo.broker.service.impl.DefStoreManagerService.startService(DefStoreManagerService.java:116)
at com.tencent.hippo.broker.ServerEngine.engineStart(ServerEngine.java:48)
at com.tencent.hippo.broker.HippoBroker$1.run(HippoBroker.java:45)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

ReplicationEnvironment has a master and a slave. when I first start the application,it runs well; but when restart the slave ,I meet the exception described above. Anybody has meet this before?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem . In my application , I start several replication Environment , but just close one when I stop the application .